# htaccess alias to subfolder of main domain

Tags: .htaccess, pointers, alias, subdirectory

I have webhosting at my main domain `website1.com` and I have an alias directing to the same server at `website2.com`. I run all my projects at `website1.com/projects/{project}`.

So what I'd like is `website2.com` to show the website contents located in `website1.com/projects/website2`.

My `.htaccess` looks as follows at this moment:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^projects/website2 /projects/website2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This works, however, when I click any link on this website, the URL will link to `website2.com/projects/website2/something.html` which I'd like to be `website2.com/something.html`.

How can I edit my `.htaccess` for this to accomplish or what am I doing wrong?

Additionally, can I add a wildcard for `*.website2.com/something.html` to refer to `projects/website2/*/something.html`?

Comment: "the url will link to `website2.com/projects/website2/something.html`" - are you saying that the internal link you click on (ie. the contents of the `href` attribute) is the URL stated? Or something else results in this filesystem path being exposed?

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for the reply, when viewing the source code, the href attribute is not exposing the file path, but when hovering my cursor over links i see (in the left bottom of the browser) a link WITH the file path so i'm not sure why this is?

Comment: What is the URL in the browser's address bar before clicking the link?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the content of a web site from an `htaccess` file. You can just point users elsewhere - what they see once they get there is not up to `mod_rewrite`.

`mod_rewrite` *rewrites requested URLs* - it has no knowledge of or control over the **content returned** after the resource has been located.

You will need to actually modify your website and/or hosting configuration to achieve this.

As a workaround, you could support those `website2/` links by adding another `RewriteRule`

```
# Your existing rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^projects/website2 /projects/website2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
# An additional rule to handle the website2 links
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^projects/website2/(.*)$ $1 [R,L,NC]
```

The path `^projects/website2/(.*)$` captures everything after `website2/` in `$1`, then return a client-side HTTP redirect. So your visitors will see `projects/website2/` in links when they hover, but the links should work, and the location bar in the browser will look how you want.

> Additionally, can I add a wildcard for .website2.com/something.html to refer to projects/website2//something.html

As far as the `.htaccess` is concerned, you just need to change the `RewriteCond` slightly: `^(www\.)?` becomes `^(.*\.)?` - instead of an optional 'www dot' this specifies an optional 'anything dot'. But the webserver will need to be look at *this* `htaccess` file for the other domain, and you can't control that here. Give it a try and you'll see pretty quickly whether it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check this modified rule, maybe it help.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !projects/website2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projects/website2/$1 [L,NC]
```